# SlidingDrawer has layout to handle invisible, and vertical center

Tags: android, layout, slidingdrawer

I'm using a **SlidingDrawer** from **Right to Left**, it's working well but I have a problem with the invisible part of android:handle, which is a LinearLayout.
I had to use a LinearLayout having a fill_parent property to permit to put my button at the *top of the view*. If I put my handle on my ImageView, 
it become vertically *centered in the middle*, and I don't want this.

*Here is my code :*

```
<SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="0dp" >

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile_top_panel_background" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/slideHandleButton"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_slider_attributes_background"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dip" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

            //DISPLAY CONTENT

                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to move the handle to exactly where I wanted was to extend the slidingdrawer class and modify the onLayout method.

This line in the sldingdrawer source code determines the position of the handle.

```
handle.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + childWidth, childTop + childHeight);
```

Extend the slidingdrawer and try adjust the values until you get the position you want.

Comment: Sorry i missed your answer ! I try it tomorrow !